# How to verify domain ownership using DNS verification?

Tags: dns, verification

I'm adding ssl certificate using zero ssl
They are asking to

> To verify domain ownership using DNS verification, you will need to
>   create DNS records of TXT type as shown below. Please remember that it
>   takes some time for new DNS records to become "visible", so you may
>   need to wait for 15-20 minutes before clicking "Next". You can check
>   whether your records became visible with the following command:
>   "nslookup -q=TXT XXX", where XXX is one of the records as shown below.

Domain TXT Record `_acme-challenge.example.com`   Value
`string_removed_here`
`_acme-challenge.example.com`   `another string here`

So what should I do here
[I'm using this blog but I think their verification steps have changed](https://thedavidweb.com/install-lets-encrypt-free-ssl-hostgator/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to go to your domain's DNS host and add the 2 TXT records there. How to add them depends on your DNS provider, but basically it should be like this:

> Type: TXT
>
> Host: _acme-challenge
>
> Value: string

and

> Type: TXT
>
> Host: _acme-challenge.www
>
> Points to: string2

Comment: Will that be possible on shared hosting ? I'm on hostgator

Comment: Note that DNS hosting and web hosting are different services. Are you sure that you use DNS service from Hostgator? If yes and if they support TXT records it should be possible. You can ask their support.

Comment: Thanks a lot I'll tri it

Answer (score 1):

First step is going into your domain's cPanel. Search for "DNS Records", "DNS Zones", or "Zone Editor". Once you've found the selection that lets you add records for the domain, create a new record of the type TXT for each Domain TXT Record provided to you through ZeroSSL.

The name/alias will be `_acme-challenge.yourdomain.com` and the value will be the text string they provide.

> The DNS Records are simply name/value pairs of various types added to your server to be queried for verification. Type TXT allows the issuer a very resource-friendly way to verify the contents, as they can be interpreted as a primitive type `string`. The name/alias they provide has a matching string on their server when it's created.

Since only the owner of the website or someone with admin access can add the record, a positive query indicates that the certificate was placed correctly.

Once you've created the record, it will take some time to become active. In order to check whether or not the TXT record you've created has been broadcast yet--if you're using Windows--open a Command Prompt and type the following:

```
nslookup -type=TXT yourdomain.com
```

The output will be all DNS text records on your domain, ensure that the _acme-challenge one is present before continuing with your ZeroSSL certification.

Answer (score 0):

To verify domain ownership using DNS verification, you will need to create DNS records of TXT type as shown below. Please remember that it takes some time for new DNS records to become "visible", so you may need to wait for 15-20 minutes before clicking "Next". You can check whether your records became visible with the following command: "nslookup -q=TXT XXX", where XXX is

How in infinityfree hosting I setup it

Comment: To verify domain ownership using DNS verification, you will need to create DNS records of TXT type as shown below. Please remember that it takes some time for new DNS records to become "visible", so you may need to wait for 15-20 minutes before clicking "Next". You can check whether your records became visible with the following command: "nslookup -q=TXT XXX", where XXX is one of the records as shown below